# How to get the current DateTime formatted in C++ (like System.DateTime.Now in .NET)

Tags: c++, .net, datetime

How to get the current DateTime in C++ like in .NET (DateTime.Now) in this format : `20/10/2014 10:53:27` ?

I have found this [library](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_date_time.htm), but this cannot perform my vows.

ny brilliant idea, please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need [std::time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) function.

Edit:

Here's example how to output current time in asked format:

```
 #include <ctime>
 #include <iostream>

 int main()
 {
     std::time_t t = std::time(NULL);
     char mbstr[100];
     if (std::strftime(mbstr, 100, "%d/%m/%Y %T", std::localtime(&t))) {
         std::cout << mbstr << '\n';
     }
 }
```

Comment: @relikd Thanks for reminding of this, even though I think it's safe to say that standard library function will always have some kind of documentation. I provided a short example.

Comment: @Predelnik, how can I convert this to string : time_t now = time(0); tm *ltm = localtime(&now); String dateAjoutSysteme = ltm->tm_mday + "/" + (1 + ltm->tm_mon) + "/" + (1900 + ltm->tm_year) + " " + (1 + ltm->tm_hour) + ":" + (1 + ltm->tm_min) + ":" + (1 + ltm->tm_sec);

Comment: @user3264174 Well you can always call `std::string` constructor from mbstr, like `std::string time_string (mbstr);` (You can omit `std::` if you're using `using namespace std` of course)

Comment: Also works with a C++ UWP application to fetch the current local time.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my Project, hope it helps

```
time_t t;
t = time(NULL);

tm tlm;

localtime_s(&tlm, &t);
cout << tlm.tm_hour << tlm.tm_min ...
```

the struct tm is explained here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

Comment: how can I convert this to string :  time_t now = time(0);
  tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
  String dateAjoutSysteme = ltm->tm_mday + "/" + (1 + ltm->tm_mon) + "/" + (1900 + ltm->tm_year) + " " + (1 + ltm->tm_hour) + ":" + (1 + ltm->tm_min) + ":" + (1 + ltm->tm_sec);

Comment: dateAjoutSysteme = ltm->tm_mday + "/" + to_string(1 + ltm->tm_mon) + "/" + to_string(1900 + ltm->tm_year) + " " + to_string(1 + ltm->tm_hour) + ":" + to_string(1 + ltm->tm_min) + ":" + to_string(1 + ltm->tm_sec);

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [boost date-time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time.html) is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

C++11: [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)?

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>
    stamp(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
```